# ngCordova plugin.keyboard undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a directive which controls the focus of an input and force the keyboard shows.

```
directives.showKeyboard = function($cordovaKeyboard)  {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("focus click",
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if(scope.$eval(attrs.showKeyboard)) {
                    $cordovaKeyboard.hideAccessoryBar(true);
                }
            }
        );
    };

    var keyboardDirective = {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: linkFn
    };

    return keyboardDirective;

}
```

The HTML:

```
<input id="search_post" type="search" placeholder="Search post" my-enter="search_posts(true)" ng-model="searchText"
                  style="width:100%;height:26px" show-keyboard="true" required>
```

When the input get focus, it arises the following error:

> ng-cordova.js:4711 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined

I've checked that the plugin and ngCordova lib is successfully installed.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code with `$ionicPlatform.ready` event.

```
directives.showKeyboard = function($cordovaKeyboard, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("focus click",
        function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (scope.$eval(attrs.showKeyboard)) {
            $cordovaKeyboard.hideAccessoryBar(true);
          }
        }
      );
    };

    var keyboardDirective = {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: linkFn
    };
    return keyboardDirective;
  });
}
```

Comment: Now, the following error arises: TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

Comment: I stll have the same issue. Always have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the issue?
If not, here is the solution:

```
angular.module('module_name',[]).directive('your_directive_name', ['$cordovaKeyboard', function(){
        restrict : 'A',
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("focus click",
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if(scope.$eval(attrs.showKeyboard)) {
                    $cordovaKeyboard.hideAccessoryBar(true);
                }
            }
        );
    };
}]
```